# React app deploy failure on github

Tags: reactjs

Can Anyone help me out that how can i deploy my react app on github. I have added all required dependecny in my package.json file with using of updated react modules.

**Below is my package.json file :**

```
    {
  "name": "git-sample-react",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "homepage": "https://ababsheck.github.io/first-react-sample/",
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.4.2",
    "react-dom": "^16.4.2",
    "react-scripts": "1.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "predeploy": "npm run build",
    "deploy": "gh-pages -d build",
    "deploy": "gh-pages -b master -d build",
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "gh-pages": "^1.2.0"
  }
}
```

**npm run deploy issue : github**

```
    Failed to get remote.origin.url (task must either be run in a git repository with a configured origin remote or must be configured with the "repo" option).
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! git-sample-react@0.1.0 deploy: `gh-pages -b master -d build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the git-sample-react@0.1.0 deploy script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\abhis\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-08-07T12_21_21_735Z-debug.log
```

Comment: seems to be an issue with gh-pages https://github.com/tschaub/gh-pages/issues/192

Answer (score 12):

I had the same issue, deploying react app in GitHub and resolved this issues with the following steeps:

1. Run the command in project folder `git remote add origin <url>`, with the URL of your repository on GitHub.
2. Run the command `npm install --save-dev gh-pages`.
3. Run the `npm run build`.
4. Run the command `npm run deploy`.
5. Change the branch in GitHub where you deploy see the image below. Under Source must be `gh-pages branch`.
   [image]

I also have added the `"homepage": "https://ababsheck.github.io/first-react-sample/",`
 before the script like:

```
"homepage": "https://ababsheck.github.io/first-react-sample/",
"scripts": {
"predeploy": "npm run build",
 ...// the rest of the code
```

Comment: I was still having same issue even after following this. Mine just got resolved by doing " npm clean-install " command.

Answer (score 0):

Best approach

`git init`

`git remote add origin <repo_link>`

`yarn add gh-pages`

`yarn build`

`yarn deploy`

Now go to your Github and update the

`Settings-->Github Pages-->source (change to gh-pages branch)-->root-->Save`

and then check the link/homepage generated.

Answer (score 0):

How to fix this problem

PS

```js
D:\Reactjs\test1> npm install --save gh-pages
npm WARN config global `--global`, `--local` are deprecated. Use `--location=global` instead.

Added 15 packages, and audited 1496 packages in 7s

232 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

6 high severity vulnerabilities

To address all issues (including breaking changes), run:
  npm audit fix --force

Run `npm audit` for details.
PS D:\Reactjs\test1> npm run deploy
npm WARN config global `--global`, `--local` are deprecated. Use `--location=global` instead.

> test1@0.1.0 predeploy
> npm run build

npm WARN config global `--global`, `--local` are deprecated. Use `--location=global` instead.

> test1@0.1.0 build
> react-scripts build

Creating an optimized production build...
Compiled successfully.

File sizes after gzip:

  46.61 kB  build\static\js\main.31b5c70f.js
    at onErrorNT (node:internal/child_process:478:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21)
Emitted 'error' event on ChildProcess instance at:
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:289:12)
    at onErrorNT (node:internal/child_process:478:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21) {
  errno: -4058,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'spawn git',
  path: 'git',
  spawnargs: [ 'config', 'user.name' ]
}
```