# Failed to get remote.origin.url

Tags: git, github, github-pages

When trying to use gh-pages to deploy a react app I get the following error

```sh
...
$ gh-pages -d build
Failed to get remote.origin.url (task must either be run in a git repository with a configured origin remote or must be configured with the "repo" option).
...
```

The remote is set as **origin**

```
$ git remote -v
origin  https://github.com/{user_name}/{repo_name} (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/{user_name}/{repo_name} (push)
```

Comment: have a look here
https://stackoverflow.com/a/53856902/8773272

Answer (score 2):

The solution for me was that I had a remote origin set, however it would throw me this error when my project folder was located on an external hard drive. Made a new react project on my local hard drive and now it works despite everything else being the same.

Answer (score 0):

I was searching for an answer too and found that I could work this around with docker.

1. Install and setup docker in your machine - https://docs.docker.com/get-docker/
2. Install node:12-alpine image - `docker run node:12-alpine`
3. start a container
4. Install `github-cli` and `git` in the container - `apk update; apk add git; apk add github-cli;`
5. Authenticate `github-cli` with PAT from Github - https://github.com/settings/tokens
6. install `gh-pages` - `npm i -D gh-pages`
7. Run `./node_modules/.bin/gh-pages -d build`
8. check whether the source of the project is set to the root of the `gh-pages` branch - https://github.com/user/repo/settings/pages

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same problem, and resolved it in very simple steps.
You may have different problems.

1. Just remove the folder `node_modules`
2. reinstall all packages using command `npm install` or `yarn`
   Try it again, if command `git remote -v` is outputting correct url, then that may be something misconfiguration in node_modules packages.